# Как телеграмм боту получить id пользователя который нажал /start

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Здравствуйте пишу бота на Python- pyTelegramBotApi. Нужно что бы при нажатии юзером на кнопку старт мне пришел его айди. как выполнить такой запрос ?

Comment: В случае с ботами, `user_id == message.chat.id`

Answer (score 7):

При нажатии юзером кнопки старт происходит отправка боту сообщения с командой 'start', а само сообщения содержит информацию, в том числе id юзера, достать который можно например таким хендлером:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
  user_id = message.from_user.id
```

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно не id пользователя, а его имя, то используйте message.from_user.username

Answer (score 1):

Обратите внимание на [`id`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.user.html?highlight=user_id) и [`from_user`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.message.html?highlight=user_id).

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    user = bot.get_me()
    userid = user.id
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, получится id бота, а не id юзера, отправившего start

Comment: нет, функция `get_me` возвращает инфу о пользователя

Comment: @idNumIT бред, только что проверил, `get_me` возвращает айди бота.