# Получение ID чата по сообщению пользователя в нем

Tags: python, telebot

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать на библиотеке Telebot, python, так чтобы бот узнавал с какого чата приходит сообщение пользователя.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как телеграмм боту получить id пользователя который нажал /start](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/839822/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-id-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%bb-start)

Answer (score 0):

У сообщения есть свойство `chat`, а у него `id`:

```
message.chat.id
```